# Mobile version of page in iframe

Tags: html, mobile, iframe

I have some page, which have mobile version (mobile version runnig automatically when we use mobile device). I would like to put that page in iframe on my page in mobile version. If is a way to force mobile version in iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the mobile device detection is now based on `user_agent`.
To enforce mobile rendering i suggest, to add "?device=mobile" to the URL of the `src` element of the iframe. Then add a simple if-condition to the mobile device detection function, which checks for `$_GET['device'] == 'mobile'` and set the rendering to "mobile".

If you are requesting the iframe via Ajax, you could try an approach, where you simply set a custom HEADER attribute.